# Creating a new sheet every month with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Hi Im involved with tourist lodges in Namibia. We record water readings ect. every day and input to an Excel file and calculate consumption per Pax , the problem is not every staff member understands Excel. So I wrote a simple Python program to input readings into excel automatically. It works the only problem is I want to save each month in a new sheet and have all the data grouped by month (eg. January(all readings) February(all readings)) . I can create a new sheet but I cannot input data to the new sheet, it just overwrites my data from the previous months... The code looks as follows

```
*import tkinter
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
import time
import datetime
book = load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
#sheet = book.active
Day = datetime.date.today().strftime("%B")
x = book.get_sheet_names()
list= x
if Day in list: # this checks if the sheet exists to stop the creation of multiple sheets with the same name
   sheet =  book.active
else:
    book.create_sheet(Day)
    sheet = book.active

#sheet = book.active*
```

And to write to the sheet I use and entry widget then save the value as follow:

```
Bh1=int(Bh1In.get())
    if Bh1 == '0':
            import Error
    else:
        sheet.cell(row=Day , column =4).value = Bh1
        number_format = 'Number'
```

Maybe I'm being stupid but please help!!

Comment: It's very bad practice to reuse a Python keyword (`list`) as a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're depending on getting the active worksheet instead of accessing it by name. Simply using something like:

```
try:
    sheet = wb[Day]
except KeyError:
    sheet = wb.create_sheet(Day)
```

is probably all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if Day in list: # this checks if the sheet exists to stop the creation of multiple sheets with the same name
   sheet =  book.get_sheet_by_name(Day) 
else:
    book.create_sheet(Day)
    book.save('sample.xlsx')
    sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name(Day)
```